# CSS3 animation - stopping @ every loop

Tags: html, css

I was trying to understand CSS3 animations. 
I took example from : 
[morphing-cubes](http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html)

In this case of infinite loop, I wanted to stop for a second after every loop. (in the Ring Model). When i use delay, it stops in the beginning of animation. How can I give delay at starting of every loop?

I used ease-out option and it kind of gives a stopping feeling but starts immediately.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you necessarily need delay here; instead of using keyword values "from" and "to", use percentages (indicated milliseconds); i took that demo and implemented this; idk if it's exactly how you envisioned it, but it is stopping after each rotation. you can add more/less percentages to the limit, to get the desired effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/MLfyv/